# Cron Job not triggered by config.xml settings

Tags: cron

I have a local module with a cron job configured in config.xml to run once per day at 10:30am:

```
<sc_followup>
    <schedule>
        <cron_expr>30 10 * * *</cron_expr>
    </schedule>
    <run>                          
        <model>followup/cron::processFollowupEmails</model>
    </run>
</sc_followup>
```

I also have the system's crontab set up to run cron.php every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * php -f /abspath/mysite/cron.php > abspath/mysite/var/log/cron.log
```

The admin cron settings are:
[image]

Lastly, I have cleared the caches.

My issue is that `processFollowupEmails()` is running once every 5 minutes instead of once per day at 10:30am. What do I need to change in my configuration to achieve that?

Comment: show please your cron_schedule table

Comment: I think my problem is that I misunderstood the use of cron.php. It seems that it is intended to execute every task without regard to the config.xml settings.

Comment: I posted the output of `crontab -l` for my web user above. I do not have access to the entire server's schedule.

Comment: No, cron work depends on table cron_schedule. Show SELECT * FROM `cron_schedule`

Comment: Is `processFollowupEmails` either a public or a static public method?

Comment: It's a public method.

Comment: My cron_schedule table is 199 lines long. Is there a specific group of entries to look for? I do see `sc_followup` present. I do not see it scheduled ahead. Each entry for it is in the past and completed. I think my mistake was not considering the "schedule ahead" setting after I changed the settings in config.xml and in the crontab.

Comment: Firstly don't call cron.php from browser. Clean your cron table. According your server config your cron calls normally. Rename your cron task (in config.xml) and just look at your table. I'm not sure (to be sure you need to look at magento Cron module) task will be created not early than 1 or a few more hours before it will be executed. In that case try to change cron time to the nearest. (check your mysql and server time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the above configuration does work for me. My mistake was in not accounting for the time between when the last cron schedule was generated and when the new schedule is generated.

When I was testing `processFollowupEmails()`, I had the config.xml settings at `*/5 * * * *`. I updated it, but it kept running every 5 minutes until the "generate schedules"/"schedule ahead" settings came around again.

I'm leaving this answer here intead of deleting the question in case any one else forgets about the scheduling ahead.